# Can I tell the Table Name of an ActiveRecord class in c#?

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to verify if a schema matches the objects I'm initializing.

Is there a way to get the TableName of a class other than simply reflecting the class name?

I am using some class with explicit TableNames

Edit: using Joe's solution I added the case where you don't specify the table name, it could probably use a constraint

```
public string find_table_name(object obj)
{
        object[] attribs = obj.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordAttribute), false);

        if (attribs != null)
        {
            ActiveRecordAttribute attrib = (Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordAttribute) attribs[0];
            if (attrib.Table != null)
                return attrib.Table;
            return obj.GetType().Name;
        }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have something like the following:

```
[ActiveRecord(Table = "NewsMaster")]
public class Article
{
    [PrimaryKey(Generator = PrimaryKeyType.Identity)]
    public int NewsId { get; set; }

    [Property(Column = "NewsHeadline")]
    public string Headline { get; set; }

    [Property(Column = "EffectiveStartDate")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Property(Column = "EffectiveEndDate")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string NewsBlurb { get; set; }
}
```

This will get you the table name:

```
    [Test]
    public void Can_get_table_name()
    {
        var attribs = typeof(Article).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordAttribute), false);

        if (attribs != null)
        {
            var attrib = (Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordAttribute) attribs[0];
            Assert.AreEqual("NewsMaster", attrib.Table);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can this be done in reverse?  IE: I want to get the module by (string)ModelClassName so that I could then go ModelClassName[] all_tag = ActiveRecordBase<ModelClassName>.FindAll(); ?? I have been working on another question here that I think needs to be done via working this same solution but backwards.  Hope that makes sense.  The question if here. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8332556/746758

Answer (score 2):

You could also use:

```
ActiveRecordModel.GetModel(typeof(Article)).ActiveRecordAtt.Table
```

see [this testcase](http://svn.castleproject.org:8080/svn/castle/trunk/ActiveRecord/Castle.ActiveRecord.Tests/PluralizationTestCase.cs)

Comment: This is the correct way to access the models table name